# How can I determine if host is reachable?

Tags: node.js

How can I determine if a certain IP address is connectable?

I need to write a small `node.js` sample that tryes to connect to `ip:port` and returns `true` or `false`, thus determining if host is reachable or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`http.get`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/all.html#http.get)

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("success");
  }
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});

function testPort(port, host, cb) {
  http.get({
    host: host, 
    port: port 
  }, function(res) {
    cb("success", res); 
  }).on("error", function(e) {
    cb("failure", e);
  });
}
```

For a tcp socket just use [`net.createConnection`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/all.html#net.createConnection)

```
function testPort(port, host, cb) {
  net.createConnection(port, host).on("connect", function(e) {
    cb("success", e); 
  }).on("error", function(e) {
    cb("failure", e);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good for interogating a HTTP server, but I need to verify if I can establish a TCP connection with a certain host.

Comment: 10x for the prompt answer. That's exactly what I needed - to establish a tcp connection

Answer (score -1):

If it is just HTTP you are interested in, you can use the HTTP HEAD request (rather than POST/GET):

```
function hostAvailable(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('HEAD', url, false);
  req.send();
  return req.status!=404;
}
```

Comment: that's for client?